# Read/Write Audio Data to Modem in OS X or Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, device, modem

I'm working on a program in Python that, for now, is on my iMac with OS X, but if I had to, I could move it to a Linux box on a Soekris box.  Also, if there's a way to do this with a command line program or a C library I can easily access from Python (still not sure how to do that, but I hear it can be done), I'm open to that.  But if it's possible to do it in Python on OS X, that would be preferred.

I have a simple (as of now) Python program for working with my modems.  It handles incoming calls with caller ID info and taking faxes on my fax line.  I would love to be able to add voice mail - nothing complex, but just being able to play back an outgoing message and record an incoming one.

But I'm having trouble finding any information on how to read or write audio data with a modem device on either OS X or Linux.

Is there anything good on handling audio data with modems on OS X or Linux?

Comment: There's some info about the relevant AT commands and data protocols here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set

Comment: @AndrewMedico: That may have solved my problem - it'll take me a day or two for testing, but if it works, I'll let you know so you can post it as an answer.  Of course I knew about AT Commands, but didn't know about voice commands as well.  Thanks.